# ASP.NET(with master page) How to get two ID in one time in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have little problem, maybe somebody knows solution??? Usually to get two ID using jQuery I do like this:

```
$('#firstID, #secondID').datepicker({ ...
```

How i can do that using jQuery in ASP.NET (with MasterPage)??? I tried this:

```
$('[id$=firstID], [id$=secondID]').datepicker({ ...
```

It work, but not very well((( Thanks advance!!!

Comment: what do you mean not very well?

Comment: when the page is loaded, it shows me two datepickers(i don't need it) and if i click on textboxes, it shows me the third and fourth

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle, as far as I've ever seen you can only have one instance of the DatePicker open at a time even if youre trying to get 2 to open it won't work

Comment: Why did you put me 1, you may think that this is a stupid question?

Comment: There is no way to tell who downvoted, but I answered your question

Comment: i will try it tomorrow, tnx!!!

Comment: my answer will work, trust me - me and countless others wet through the headache of jQuery in webforms with masterpages, just use classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have no clue what you are talking about as far as 3 or 4 datepicker's opening at the sae time, but to answer your question, the easiest best way is to do this

```
$('.firstClass, .secondClass').datepicker({ ...
```

obviously classes would need to be assigned to the textboxes in the master page.  Classes can be accessed from the child page where the ids get mangled and (can not as easily)

Answer (score 0):

i tried using following code and its working fine

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {             $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_strtdatepicker,#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_enddatepicker").datepicker();            
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="strtdatepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="enddatepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: that will assign the value of secondID

Comment: yes but i made some changes and its working fine you can use same

Comment: that code is still no good - try in Chrome  FireFox , then IE - you will see that prefix "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_" is different in each browser and unpredictable as browsers update themselves

Comment: tnx, but i know this solution!!! i dont like this: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_! i want to use real ID!

Comment: yes, you can replace this ids with your control ids its not necessary to keep these ids it will change as per your control ids and this solution is working on chrome as well as IE also so check once again

Comment: @rahul.deshmukh : bhau upvote karun dila aahe. Marathi manasala downvote karanara aajun janmala yaycha aahe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("#firstID, #secondID").each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your code inside page load. you can use your code inside the document.ready function():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstID, #secondID').each(function(){
         $(this).datepicker({ 
         });
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstID, #secondID').datepicker({ });
});
```